# API Manager, anaylytics and MYSQL Connection Time Out Issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I keep getting connection timed out. The following are my connection configuration properties and the connection timed out exception is also below. for some reason, it keeps timing out after 15  minutes. Is there some other configuration I am to add or the right combination of these connection properties will make the error go away?

## my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout = 86400
interactive_timeout = 86400
connect_timeout = 120
```

## `worker/deployment.yaml`

```
  // APIM_ANALYTICS_DB analytics database
  jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://some_ip:some_port/api-manager-stats?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true'
  username: some_username
  password: some_password
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  maxPoolSize: 300
  idleTimeout: 288000000
  connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
  validationTimeout: 300000000
  isAutoCommit: false
```

## `dashboard/deployment.yaml`

```
// main wso2 API manager database WSO2AM_DB
jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://some_ip:some_port/api-manager-admin?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true'
username: some_username
password: some_password
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
maxPoolSize: 10
idleTimeout: 60000
connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
validationTimeout: 30000
isAutoCommit: false

// analytics database config APIM_ANALYTICS_DB
jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:mysql://some_ip:some_port/api-manager-analytics?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true'
username: some_username
password: some_password
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
maxPoolSize: 50
idleTimeout: 60000
connectionTestQuery: SELECT 1
validationTimeout: 30000
isAutoCommit: false
```

> ERROR {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.task.MGWFileReaderTask} - Error occurred while publishing micro-gateway API Usage data. org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.exception.MGWFileSourceException: Error occurred while getting the next files to process.
> at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.dao.MGWFileSourceDAO.getNextFilesToProcess(MGWFileSourceDAO.java:155)
> at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.task.MGWFileReaderTask.run(MGWFileReaderTask.java:59)
> at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
> at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-4 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 937982ms.
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:697)
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 2,101,021 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 937,983 milliseconds ago.
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor73.newInstance(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)

Comment: Did you enable apim.analytics in wso2 api manager deployment.toml ? or you are using microgateway?

Comment: @chashikajw yes I did enable analytics

Comment: so in your case, your analytics is working correctly( which means you can see the data in the analytics dashboard) but you getting the above timeout error?

Comment: @chashikajw yes I can see data although the data is not accurate as some of them failed to reach the database due to this timeout issue.